# Shuffled results not sending to database in the shuffled order

Tags: php, mysql, shuffle

I have a page I am shuffling users order. I am wanting to send the results of that order into my database so that I can use that order for something later on. I thought the results were sending in the order that they appeared when shuffling them, but it is not and I am not sure exactly what order they are being sent.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3, 4 ,5)");

echo 'Users to be given draft order: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="

POST" name="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="shuffle">
     <input type="hidden" name="shuffleButton" value="1">
</form>

Shuffled results: <br>
<div class="main-bag">     
<div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div> 
 <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $result) :
$count++;
$shuffle_count = $count;
    $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
    $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
    $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
    $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
    $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_count; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">

<?php 

    endforeach;
     if ( isset($_POST['shuffleButton'] ) ) :
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">';
    endif;

?>
</form>
<?php        
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $ordering_number = "1";

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $draft_stmt1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  if ( false===$draft_stmt1|| false===$draft_stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $draft_stmt1->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];

        $draft_stmt1->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($draft_stmt1->error));
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would not be sending in the order I am shuffling it? I have a base id field in my database table so that each inserted user would be given the id in the order that they were being drafted, but it is not working that way.

Sorry for all of the code, I wanted to be sure not to forget something that could be helpful Thanks!

UPDATE

New Code

```
  $draft_stmt1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (id, user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

 if ( false===$draft_stmt1|| false===$draft_stmt2 || false===$draft_stmt3) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $draft_stmt1->bind_param('iissss', $i, $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];

        $draft_stmt1->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($draft_stmt1->error));
```

This is where the the users are shuffled from..

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE group IN (3,4,5) ORDER BY id");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
$array[] = array( 
'id' => $row['id'],
'firstname' => $row['firstname'], 
'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 
'username' => $row['username'], 
'email' => $row['email'] 
); 

if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {

   }
}
shuffle($array);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: The order that you insert stuff into a database is not something to rely on. There is no guarantee that the database will return the data in the order you want it to unless you explicitly use an ORDER BY

Comment: How could I add `ORDER BY` in my query to put this in the order the users were shuffled?

Comment: I see lots of variables with "shuffle" in the name, but I don't see where you're actually calling a function that rearranges the array.

Comment: Add a `shuffle_order` column to the table, and put `$i` in that.

Comment: Like I said you don't order an insert. You order a select.

Comment: @e4c5 If I order the select, won't that take away the effect of the shuffle??

Comment: Use `ORDER BY shuffle_order`.

Comment: So this? `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE group IN (3,4,5) ORDER BY shuffle_order"`

Comment: You should have a new table and just insert one row with a string of shuffled user ids

Comment: @Paul Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Barmar That kills the code.

Comment: Paul i do believe Barmar has given you the solution. If you feel that doesn't still solve your problem further explainations are needed. You should tell us what your current table looks like as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column `shuffle_order` to the table, and store the order that the players were received from the form in this column.

```
$draft_stmt1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (shuffle_order, user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
if ( false===$draft_stmt1|| false===$draft_stmt2 ) {
    // Check Errors for prepare
    die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$draft_stmt1->bind_param('iissss', $i, $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
    $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
    $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
    $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
    $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];

    $draft_stmt1->execute() or
        die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($draft_stmt1->error));
}
```

Then when you want to process the data in the shuffled order, use `ORDER BY shuffle_order` in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: If I have an id field that is set to auto increment in that table shouldn't it do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, you could use that.

Comment: It still is killing the code. I have error reporting on and it is not throwing any errors. I updated my question with the current code.

Comment: Killing it in what way? What exactly is it doing?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. The names are not displaying. They are in the source code though, but even in the source code they are not shuffled, they are just ordered by the id like it has in the query, but I need these names to be in a shuffled order.

Comment: You can see what it is doing here... http://sundayfundayleague.com/test_shuffle3.php ... When you press the Create Draft Order button you see nothing happens and then if you look at the source code, nothing is displaying.

Comment: I see an error in the Javascript console: _Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list test_shuffle3.php:19_

Comment: You're missing a `+`  at the end of the third line in the `$('#results').append()` call.

Comment: I added that to that and now I have a token error for the first line?

Comment: Go to the Network tab and look at the response from the AJAX call. It's returning a MySQL error message: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>/home4/pfarley1/public_html/sundayfundayleague.com/shuffle_results.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
[]

Comment: You need to add error checking to the `mysqli_query()` call, and return the error message for that.

Comment: That is for this line in my php file that I posted in my question where I am selecting from the database... `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { `

Comment: I know that. That's why you need to check if the query succeeded before trying to fetch the results.

Comment: I have this in the file... `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: SQL errors aren't reported by PHP error reporting. You have to do `if (!$query) { die($con->error); }`

Comment: Just like you do in the script with the `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I get this in the console... `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group IN ([3, 4, 5]) ORDER BY id' at line 1` Then it has some numbers under it? 0: 3, 1:4 and 2:5.

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word. You have to put it in backticks to use it as a column name.

Comment: `WHERE group IN (3, 4, 5)` was in your query even before you added my suggestions. I don't understand why you didn't run into this problem earlier.

Comment: Not sure. That is fixed now, but it isn't sending in order or assigning the id as the inserted order. For example, I click the create draft order button and get this `0 Jackee Calhoun
1 Paul Farley
2 Keith Calhoun
3 test
4 Mike Calhoun
5 Jeric Whittaker
6 Andrew Haas` and then get this order in my db `3
86
Keith

6
94
Jackee

5
93
Andrew


4
89
Jeric
Whittaker

2
85
Mike

1
6
test


273
1
Paul`

Comment: the first number being the id the second the userid and then the name.

Comment: When you do the AJAX call, you're putting the shuffled results in `<div id="results">`, not in the `<form>`. So the shuffled names aren't being sent when you submit the form.

Comment: I put the `<div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div>` into the form and now it is sending two sets of results. One of those is sending correctly, except the user with the 0 keep getting an id of 274?, but how can I get it to only send it once? `<form method="post"><div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert"></form>`

Comment: Take the other fields out of the form.

Comment: They're all hidden, aren't they? The form should only contain the ones that are added by the AJAX code that gets the shuffled names.

Comment: ok. I took out the hidden inputs and it is working for the most part. It is sending that number 0 person as 279 instead of one. Do you have any idea why the first number is sending as id 279 instead of 1?

Comment: Where are you seeing that? The `$i` values in the `foreach` loop should just run from 0 to the number of items.

Comment: Are you looking at `$_POST['id']`? That's the ID from the `users` table.

Comment: Well you can see the first drafted user in my test page shows up as 0. For some reason that record once inserted into the db table is showing up as some value in the 200's. Which after doing this a couple more time, it seems that number is increasing at an auto increment every time I try to send this into my db. So the last time I did this the first user drafted was 279 and I just did it again and the first user drafted was given the id of 280. The other users drafted appear in order like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc, just like they should. The user_id field is their userid